# Retrieve autoincrement primary key values from SQLite table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a table created as:

```
sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable(ID AUTO_INCREMENT, myField VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID));";
```

After adding a few records, I want to retrieve the ID values, like this:

```
sql="SELECT ID FROM myTable"

Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
resultSet.moveToFirst();
```

Here, `resultSet.getCount`  shows a number of records but `resultSet.getInt()` always give 0;

Any idea how to retrieve ID-s?

Answer (score 2):

The answer of you question...`You can't.`

Some other help:

You can select all IDs once by

```
    public String getId() {
        String ids = "";
        String[] columns = new String[] {ID,..};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(LOCATER_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,null, null);
        int id = c.getColumnIndex(ID);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            ids = ids + "\n"+c.getColumnIndex(LOCATER_ID);              
        }

        return ids;
    }
```

Or a particular Id through some same row item/reference..like `select id where name = ..` or something like this.